# No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found with default authentification and custom authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.0 app and have a problem with authorization. I want to use custom authorization with special requests. Header and standard default authentication.
First, I add configuration in `Startup.cs`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(DefaultAuthorizedPolicy, policy =>
        {
            policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenAuthRequirement());
        });
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthTokenPolicy>();
    // ...
}
```

`AuthTokenPolicy.cs`:

```
public class AuthTokenPolicy : AuthorizationHandler<TokenAuthRequirement>
{   
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TokenAuthRequirement requirement)
    {
        var filterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        try
        {
            // some validation code

            var isValidToken = isValidTokenTask.Result;
            if (!isValidToken)
            {
                response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and in `HomeController.cs`:

```
[Authorize(Policy = Startup.DefaultAuthorizedPolicy)]
public async Task<IActionResult> IsVisible()
```

If I use the wrong request.header in `AuthTokenPolicy` I see it, but in the logs I see this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.d__14.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at React.AspNet.BabelFileMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at core.common.Middleware.LoggingMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext() in D:\Dev\microservicePDP\Template\core.common\Middleware\LoggingMiddleware.cs:line 72

After reading [Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) I've added this code in startup.cs

Quotation from the article :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

> Define a default scheme in 2.0 if one of the following conditions is true:
>   You want the user to be automatically signed in
>   You use the [Authorize] attribute or authorization policies without specifying schemes

I added `AuthenticationScheme` and `DefaultChallengeScheme` in `ConfigureServices()`. It didn't help, the same error here. I've tried to use `app.UseAuthentication();` in the `Startup.Configure()` method, with no results.

How can I use a custom authorization without authentication?

Comment: so after using `AddAuthentication`, you again used `[Authorize(Policy = Startup.DefaultAuthorizedPolicy)]` ?

Comment: Yes. Isn't right?

Comment: I was just confirming what you wrote. I am assuming `DefaultChallengeScheme` only gets set for the default authroize policy.... either ways try my answer

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Do not use authorization instead of authentication. I should get whole access to service all clients with header.

The working code is:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<TokenAuthenticationOptions> 
{
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public TokenAuthenticationHandler (IOptionsMonitor<TokenAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
        : base (options, logger, encoder, clock) 
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync () 
    {
        var headers = Request.Headers;
        var token = "X-Auth-Token".GetHeaderOrCookieValue (Request);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (token)) {
            return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Fail ("Token is null"));
        }           

        bool isValidToken = false; // check token here

        if (!isValidToken) {
            return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Fail ($"Balancer not authorize token : for token={token}"));
        }

        var claims = new [] { new Claim ("token", token) };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity (claims, nameof (TokenAuthenticationHandler));
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket (new ClaimsPrincipal (identity), this.Scheme.Name);
        return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Success (ticket));
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
#region Authentication
services.AddAuthentication (o => {
    o.DefaultScheme = SchemesNamesConst.TokenAuthenticationDefaultScheme;
})
.AddScheme<TokenAuthenticationOptions, TokenAuthenticationHandler> (SchemesNamesConst.TokenAuthenticationDefaultScheme, o => { });
#endregion
```

And mycontroller.cs:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = SchemesNamesConst.TokenAuthenticationDefaultScheme)]
public class MainController : BaseController
{ ... }
```

I can't find TokenAuthenticationOptions now, but it was empty. I found the same class PhoneNumberAuthenticationOptions:

```
public class PhoneNumberAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public Regex PhoneMask { get; set; }// = new Regex("7\\d{10}");
}
```

You should define static class `SchemesNamesConst`. Something like:

```
public static class SchemesNamesConst
{
    public const string TokenAuthenticationDefaultScheme = "TokenAuthenticationScheme";
}
```

Comment: Where is TokenAuthenticationOptions class from? did you define it yourself or is it from a library?

Comment: Hello. I can't find TokenAuthenticationOptions now, but it was empty. I found the same class PhoneNumberAuthenticationOptions and added it to first comment

Comment: Where is SchemesNamesConst defined?

Comment: Hello. I've updated first comment, it was defined in static class. I have not the same but very similar project here https://github.com/galenam/MicroserviceTemplate

Comment: I don't downvote but please avoid do not-objective conclussions about your answer like "this is the best answer" or something like. This is not a forum, and in my case it wont help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try:
public  class TokenAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions { }

Comment: Policy-based authorization (without authentication) is recommended approach from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 49):

this worked for me

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/auth/denied");
        });
```

Comment: Yep, this one is the simplest solution

Comment: Don't forget to use app.UseAuthentication();

Answer (score 7):

I landed on this question after I tried to use an AuthorizationHandler without authentication. I was trying to automatically verify a captcha based on a policy, so I could apply the policy to all the endpoints which had to be protected with a captcha.

I ended with the same failure when I wanted to throw 401 or 403 if the captcha couldn't be verified.

I don't like any of the solutions here because they are *hacky*, they try to use authentication and authorization when we are not really doing any, after all ASP.NET Core kind of ties Authorization with Authentication because in their design principle you can't decide if someone is authorized if you don't know who that person is.

This made me realize you can *sometimes* (depends on your requirements) use a resource filter instead of trying to hack the authorization filter to work as you want it to work, leaving the authentication/authorization system alone, and independent.

This solution **might not be adapted to everyone** but it might help those who like me do not need authentication but just decide if a controller should be accessible based on something else than the identity of the person using the endpoint.

```cs
public class YourResourceFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    //any services you might need through DI (dependency injection)
    private readonly ICaptchaService captchaService;
    public YourResourceFilter(ICaptchaService captchaService)
    {
        this.captchaService = captchaService;
    }
    //this is where you need to code any logic related to your requirements.
    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        //in my case I needed to get a header value, and verify it using my captcha service.
        //but you should be able to do almost anything here because you have access to DI.
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("captcha", out var values))
        {
            var response = values.FirstOrDefault();
            if (response != null && await captchaService.VerifyCaptchAsync(response))
            {
                await next(); //if all is OK then keep going.
                return;
            }
        }
        //if not then set the status code to whatever you want. In my case I wanted to return 403 when the captcha couldn't be verified.
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    }
}
```

Now, how do we run this filter on the controllers? And how do we use dependency injection on the resource?

You'll need to create an attribute which inherits ServiceFilterAttribute as such:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This applies your own resource filter whenever you apply this attribute on a controller endpoint.
/// </summary>
public class YourResourceFilterAttribute : ServiceFilterAttribute
{
    public YourResourceFilterAttribute() : base(typeof(YourResourceFilter))
    {
    }
}
```

Finally do not forget to register your filter with your dependency injection container:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<YourResourceFilter>();
```

And apply it to any controller which you want to apply this on:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous] //you can add this attribute is you want to bypass any authentication/authorization set up on that Asp.net core project, so you can use it no matter what configuration you have on the authentication/authorization system
[YourResourceFilter]
[HttpPost]
public Task ExampleAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // whatever code your controller endpoint has
}
```

**TL:DR:**

Using a `IAsyncResourceFilter` and a `ServiceFilterAttribute` to apply your custom request logic is a more flexible and less hacky approach than the ones above.

1. Implement  an `IAsyncResourceFilter` which holds your logic on your 'authorization' without authentication.
2. Inherit a ServiceFilterAttribute to create an attribute which applies your filter to whatever controller you put the attribute on. It's compatible with or without authentication. If you want to bypass any existing authentication/authorization system just apply the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, if you have any.
3. Register your filter created in 1. with your dependency injection container.
4. Add the attribute you created in 2. to any controller endpoints you want to apply your custom logic.

**Conclusion**

This approach is a lot more flexible than hacking the Authorization feature to work without authentication which it clearly wasn't designed to do. Plus you have the great advantage that this will work regardless of the authentication/authorization system, so if later you add any to your API, you can still verify these parameters on whatever endpoint you want. IMO this is a cleaner and simpler approach in the end.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I wanted some way of protecting (authorizing) my endpoints via header api key. I went with implementing custom policy-based AuthorizationHandler but ASP.NET Core also requires establishing Default Authentication Scheme which I currently want to avoid. So adding this filter is really elegant solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

When I used policy before I set the default authentication scheme into it as well. I had modified the `DefaultPolicy` so it was slightly different. However the same should work for add policy as well.

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(DefaultAuthorizedPolicy, policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenAuthRequirement());
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string>()
        {
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        }
    });
});
```

Do take into consideration that by Default `AuthenticationSchemes` property uses a read only list. I think it would be better to implement that instead of List as well.

Comment: Just tryed, the exception is difficult : "No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Cookies" . I prefer not to write custom cookie auth and can't google something useful for new exception.

Comment: yeah. you need to add cookies `AddAuthentication().AddCookie()`

Comment: Hello. I've added AddAuthentication().AddCookie() and policy.AuthenticationSchemes and after that I have 200 Ok status with right token and 404 with wrong token. I debugged code and saw status=401 in method in TokenAuthPolicy.HandleRequirementAsync but client received 404. Have you any idea where net core changes the status from 401 to 404 ?

Comment: if you are using tokens, you can try `.AddJTW()` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your initial statement in the marked solution isn't entirely true. While your new solution may accomplish your original goal, it is still possible to circumvent the original error while preserving your AuthorizationHandler logic--*provided* you have basic authentication scheme handlers in place, even if they are functionally skeletons.

Speaking broadly, Authentication Handlers and schemes are meant to establish + validate identity, which makes them required for Authorization Handlers/policies to function--as they run on the supposition that an identity has already been established.

ASP.NET Dev Haok summarizes this best best here: "Authentication today isn't aware of authorization at all, it only cares about producing a ClaimsPrincipal per scheme. Authorization has to be aware of authentication somewhat, so AuthenticationSchemes in the policy is a mechanism for you to associate the policy with schemes used to build the effective claims principal for authorization (or it just uses the default httpContext.User for the request, which does rely on DefaultAuthenticateScheme)."
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1469

In my case, the solution I'm working on provided its own implicit concept of identity, so we had no need for authentication schemes/handlers--just header tokens for authorization. So until our identity concepts changes, our header token authorization handlers that enforce the policies can be tied to 1-to-1 scheme skeletons.

Tags on endpoints:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AuthenticatedUserSchemeName", Policy = "AuthorizedUserPolicyName")]
```

Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "AuthenticatedUserSchemeName";
        }).AddScheme<ValidTokenAuthenticationSchemeOptions, ValidTokenAuthenticationHandler>("AuthenticatedUserSchemeName", _ => { });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AuthorizedUserPolicyName", policy =>
            {
                //policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Sid,"authToken");
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("AuthenticatedUserSchemeName");
                policy.AddRequirements(new ValidTokenAuthorizationRequirement());
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ValidTokenAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Both the empty authentication handler *and* authorization handler are called (similar in setup to OP's respective posts) but the authorization handler still enforces our authorization policies.

Comment: Where do I get this from? `ValidTokenAuthenticationSchemeOptions`, `ValidTokenAuthenticationHandler`, `ValidTokenAuthorizationRequirement` ? It is not part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` and I could not find it easily on Google.