# HowTo handle custom policy based authorization in ASP.NET Core in case of fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made my own custom policy based authorization like described in the MS Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies).

My question is about how to handle a non sucessful authorization:

```
public class MinimumAgeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Fail(); //<-- Simplified    
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

If my authorization doesn't set `context.Suceed(requirement)` or explicitly calls `context.Fail()`  an exception of type `InvalidOperationException` is thrown.

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
>   there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

I was hoping to get another type of Exception that contains `MinimumAgeRequirement` so that I could be able to show a Custom Error like "Hey you're too young for that stuff".

Is there a way to get the information out when catching the Exception?

Comment: Can you include the AddAuthentication code from your startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found with default authentification and custom authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324129/no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme-f)

Comment: @RuardvanElburg AddAuthentication or AddAuthorization ? (I don't have any AddAuthentication code)

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I've added AddAuthentication `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(...` now I get redirected to the LoginPath. But still how do I know there what exactly happened? Thanks

Comment: With the schemes you specify how to handle certain security situations, like Authenticate, Forbid, etc. You can use all kinds of schemes, like oidc, bearer, cookie, MyScheme. So when a user needs to be authenticated, the user is challenged using a scheme. If none is provided, the default scheme is used (cookie). Now you've configured this, the server can handle the request. In the resource you can define the scheme which should be challenged: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x or manually: .ChallengeAsync("Bearer")