# Return a custom response when using the Authorize Attribute on a controller

Tags: rest, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token, authorize-attribute

I have just implemented the Bearer token and I have added the Authorize attribute to my controller class and that works fine. It looks like this:

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

What I would like to do is to create a more complex response from the server when it fails, rather then the standard 401.

I tried filters but they are not invoked at all.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a custom scheme, custom authorization handler and poof!

Notice that I injected the Handler in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;
            })
                .AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(
                    ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, o => { });
```

*ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions*

```
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
        public const string DefaultScheme = "API Key";
        public string Scheme => DefaultScheme;
        public string AuthenticationType = DefaultScheme;
        public const string HeaderKey = "X-Api-Key";
    }
```

*ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An Auth handler to handle authentication for a .NET Core project via Api keys.
    ///
    /// This helps to resolve dependency issues when utilises a non-conventional method.
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324129/no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme-f
    /// </summary>
    public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, 
            UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
            : base (options, logger, encoder, clock) 
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() 
        {
            var token = Request.Headers[ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.HeaderKey];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) {
                return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Fail ("Token is null"));
            }

            var customRedisEvent = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICustomRedisEvent>();
            var isValidToken = customRedisEvent.Exists(token, RedisDatabases.ApiKeyUser);

            if (!isValidToken) {
                return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Fail ($"Invalid token {token}."));
            }

            var claims = new [] { new Claim ("token", token) };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity (claims, nameof (ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler));
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket (new ClaimsPrincipal (identity), Scheme.Name);
            return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Success (ticket));
        }
    }
```

Focus on the handler class. Apart from the sample code I've provided, simply utilise the base class properties like `Response` to set your custom http status code or whatever you may need!

Here's the derived class if you need it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1