# "No authenticationScheme was specified" when I deploy, but works fine on my machine

Tags: asp.net, iis

We're deploying our little intranet app for the first time (.net6, IIS8.5).

I'm surprised to see "**No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found**. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions)"

Surprised because I've specified the default authentication scheme exactly as the error suggests. Our startup is completely vanilla, and all this works fine on our dev machines. What could possibly be the problem? The relevant parts of our startup are as follows...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // Authorization always Yes for testing
        if (!_env.IsProduction())
        {
            // Disable authentication and authorization.
            services.RemoveAll<IPolicyEvaluator>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator>();
        }

        ...
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        ...
    }
```

Comment: The same question you can use as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324129/no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme-f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324129/no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme-f).

Answer (score 0):

Ok in my case this was hopelessly simple. I needed to turn on Windows Authentication in IIS for my website. It is off by default. Hope this can be useful.