# AuthorizationFilter throws exception

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization, iauthorizationfilter

Trying to register an `AuthorizationFilter` against my controllers. I have previously set one up but that is an `IActionFilter` but when doing the same thing with an `AuthorizationFilter` instead it throws this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
```

My code looks like this:
**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => {
    options.Filters.Add<SecureByDefaultFilter>();
    options.Filters.Add<AuthorisedFilter>();
});
```

**AuthorizationFilter that doesn't work**

```
internal class AuthorisedFilter : IAuthorizationFilter {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
            var authorizedAttribute = context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<AuthorisedAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (authorizedAttribute?.Roles == "Public") {
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(authorizedAttribute?.Roles);
        }
    }
```

**Action filter that works**

```
internal class SecureByDefaultFilter : IActionFilter {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
            var authorizedAttribute = context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<AuthorisedAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            
            if (authorizedAttribute == null) {
                throw new MissingAttributeException("Endpoint missing Authorised Attribute");
            }      
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }
    }
```

Comment: Setting the default schemes using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions) or specifying authenticationScheme seems like a good first step maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found with default authentification and custom authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324129/no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme-f)

Comment: I'll give something a try thanks