# How can I use Authorize attribute in .net core 6 razor pages?

Tags: .net

I have 2 projects.

1- Web
2- Api

In my login web page, I am hitting the API authinticate method.

here is my code:

```
 var userName = Request.Form["UserName"].ToString();
            var password = Request.Form["Password"].ToString();
            var login = new Models.Login();
            login.UserName = userName;
            login.Password = password;
            // Hit the api and check user name and password the request.
            var apiUrl = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("AppSettings")["BaseUrl"] +
                "/api/Authenticate/Authenticate";
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
                var response = client.UploadString(apiUrl, Json);
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.LoginResponseModel>(response);
                if(result.code != 200)
                {
                    InvalidLogin = true;
                    return this.Page();
                }
                else
                {
                    var s = string.Format($"Bearer {0}", result.Message);
                    Response.Headers.Add("Authorization",s);
                    return  new RedirectToPageResult("/Employees");
                }

            }
```

Now if things went fine.

I am redirecting users to Employees Page.

now if I use Authorize attribute in Employees page

```
   [Authorize]
    public class EmployeesModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
```

I know as a workaround, I can check if token is there in the get of employees page like this:

```
  public void OnGet()
   {
     if (Request.Headers["Authorization"])
     {
        
     }
   }
```

Any ideas ?

I did this workaround:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Token", result.Message);
```

in my controller api logout:

```
        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpGet]
        public void Logout()
        {
            // Remove Token;
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Token", "");
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found with default authentification and custom authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324129/no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme-f)

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen no, Actullay, I do not understand how token works properly, can u share your knowlege please ?