# .NET Core 2.1 Authorization based on Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I am supporting an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API which returns client data. This API is hosted on the company's intranet on an IIS server. As of now, there is no authentication and anyone on the company's intranet can access the API.

Recently there was a change in the requirement to split the current method on the API into three different methods.

The first method should be open to all intranet users and will return very few client details. The second method will be limited to set of users belonging to the Active Directory group `Ad-L1-Users`. And the third method is restricted to users in the Active Directory group `Ad-L2-Users`.

This is my `launchsettings.json` file

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": false, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51100",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "BFApiDemo": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("L1-Users", policy =>
                policy.RequireRole("Ad-L1-Users"));

            options.AddPolicy("L2-Users", policy =>
                policy.RequireRole("Ad-L2-Users"));
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

I am using authorize attribute on action method as below

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Ad-L1-Users")]
```

when I run the application from command prompt using dotnet run and hit the end point I am getting this exception :

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Am I missing anything? I am using Visual Studio Code for my development and running it on my local machine. I am not using Azure AD

Comment: Have you checked out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48903116/18278998)?

Comment: If you're doing active development on this application, I suggest you upgrade it to .NET 6. .NET Core 2.1 has been out-of-support for over 2 years.

Comment: @Roe Thanks for sharing the link. Where can i specify my ad groups?

Comment: @MartinCostello, thanks but due to few constraints we don't have any plan to upgrade.

Comment: Fair enough, but that means you've got 2 years worth of unpatched security vulnerabilities in your app.

Comment: @MandarPatil Shot in the dark since I have never used active directory. But [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/adam/creating-groups) Might help you (the c# code is at the bottom of the page, the rest is in VB)

Comment: When a secure client/server connection is made using HTTPS, TLS is used to establish an encrypted connection.   TLS uses a certificate with a key and encryption mode.  A IIS server may not work with many certificates.  Only TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are valid (older version have been obsoleted).  The after connection is established authentication is used.  The upgrade on your server is probably using OAUTH2 where a token is obtained.  See picture in following : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph

Comment: For the no schema issue, I suggest you could try to follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#iisiis-express) to enable the windows authentication by using the  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate package.